# Build a dll with static libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, isapi

I want to build a DLL to use it as an IIS/ISAPI application. So far so good. It works. However, I have to drag arround the runtime dll and other dependencies (like some boost libraries).

I would like to make a single DLL (in order to ease the deployment on multiple servers).

So I changed the switch from /MD to /MT. However, now I get errors of duplicate symbols during link. For example :

```
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void)" (??_D?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in gateway.obj
```

I'm puzzled that /MD or /MT are compiler flags and not linkers flags. And it could in some way explain why I get duplicated symbols (as the will be included in each .obj).

So the question is: how do I configure visual studio 10 in order to get a dll that includes all its dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/MD` and `/MT` switches only apply to the Microsoft C runtime library and not 3rd party libraries.  [This documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) gives some information on why it is a compiler switch (they cause different defines to be created during the compilation).

Pulling 3rd party DLLs directly into your own DLL as static libraries is probably not a simple process unless static libraries already exist.  I don't know of any standard method for turning a DLL into a static library.  A quick Internet search indicates that there exist tools that claim to do that process (my quick search did not turn up any free ones).  But I think the most robust solution would be to use existing static libraries if you can.  I believe you can build static versions of the Bools libraries, which you could then specify in your link statement in Visual Studio (as opposed to naming the libraries for the DLLs).

Comment: Thank you... This litte information that it only applies to runtime made thing way easier ;)